# RESTified GraphQL Endpoints with query parameter

Tags: graphql, hasura

I want to make a REST endpoint out of my Hasura schema. I am trying to include some variables as query parameters in url like `rest/:MetricId?page=:Page&size=:Size`, but this format doesn't work. I was able to make another endpoint with path variables `rest/:MetricId/:Page/:Size`, but this is not a standard pagination pattern. I read through the RESTify endpoints doc but still can't figure how to include query params in the REST endpoints. I am creating the endpoint from the console. Any tips?